# Flutter push notifications using Socket IO and NodeJS Backend, is it Possible?

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io, push-notification

I'm planning to develop a native app for an already-built web app and nodeJS server that uses socket IO for real-time updates, my concern is if I can generate push notifications using socket io even when the user is away from the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something simple, i will advice you to use firebase.

But if you still want to use socket.io, you can do it. The app listen for event emitting and when receive the event, trigger a [local notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications).
Check this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) to learn more about background process.

Comment: can I use firebase on nodeJS, while my database is on MongoDB?

Comment: Yes you will not use firebase to replace all the database you are using currently. You just need to implement the notification feature with it.